# SBT Resolvers work in build.sbt, not working in Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt

Once upon a time, in a far off land, there existed a project with a little `project/build.sbt` file that looks like this:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("scala-js-snapshots",
  url("http://repo.scala-js.org/repo/snapshots/")
)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" % "scalajs-sbt-plugin" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT")
```

At project load time, things looked great, and there was peace in the land:

```
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.scalajs.org/repo/snapshots/org.scalalang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-sbtplugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2-SNAPSHOT/jars/scalajs-sbt-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-sbt-plugin;0.2SNAPSHOT!scalajs-sbt-plugin.jar (1936ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

One day, another project was created. Unlike the first project, this project was big and complicated, and so it has a `project/project/Build.scala` which looks like this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
object Build extends sbt.Build {
  import sbt._

  override lazy val projects = Seq(root)
  lazy val root =
    Project("plugins", file("."))
      .settings(
        resolvers += Resolver.url("scala-js-snapshots",
          url("http://repo.scala-js.org/repo/snapshots/")
        )(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
        addSbtPlugin("org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" % "scalajs-sbt-plugin" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT")
      )
      .dependsOn(uri("../../scala-js-resource/plugin"))
      .dependsOn(uri("../../scala-js-workbench"))
}
```

It seemed to me that this should set up the SBT plugin in an identical way to the earlier arrangement. After all, what is a `build.sbt` but a bunch of settings? The only difference was that it depended on some other local projects and thus couldn't be a plain `.sbt` file.

But at load time, something terrible happened:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-sbt-plugin;0.2-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalalang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalalang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.2-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Haoyi\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs\scalajs-sbt-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.2-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scalajs/scalajs-sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.2-SNAPSHOT/scalajs-sbt-plugin-0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Stupid `Build.scala`, you didn't even try the resolver I gave you! I even told you where to look for the damn module, why did you give up without even trying? Your little brother the `build.sbt` found it perfectly fine.

Anyone know what gives, and how I can make the `Build.scala` work like I want it to?

Answer (score 6):

`project/build.sbt` is *not* the little brother of `project/Build.scala`. The former defines sbt *plugins*, whereas the latter is the actual build file. Its little brother, if you want, would be `<root-dir>/build.sbt`.

You should leave the plugin definitions in `project/build.sbt`. There is nothing wrong with having both files.

Your project definition (along with the `dependsOn`) should either be in `project/Build.scala`, or you use `<root-dir>/build.sbt` where in sbt 0.13 you can basically do everything that was formerly restricted to `Build.scala`, so my advise is to only use `.sbt` files these days.

---

So leave `project/build.sbt`, or better rename it to `project/plugins.sbt` so there is less confusion, and use this as `./build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = Project("plugins", file("."))
  .dependsOn(uri("../scala-js-resource/plugin"))
  .dependsOn(uri("../scala-js-workbench"))
```

Comment: It's `project/project/Build.scala` not `project/Build.scala` though. I'm pretty sure those are both meant to handle plugins. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @LiHaoyi - ok, but that still means the OP is trying to mix plugin definitions with project definitions. I am actually surprised that you can _define a project_ in a build file that is in a plugin location.

Comment: I don't think that's right; my plugin definitions are in either `project/build.sbt` or `project/project/Build.scala` for the two projects, and my project definitions are in `project/Build.scala`. I'm sorry if the OP wasn't clear on this. Is this not the right way of doing things?

Comment: @LiHaoyi exactly. Sorry, I'm just seeing that _you are_ the OP. In the question, you post the contents of `project/project/Build.scala` which is (as you say in your comment as well) a _plugin_ definition file. But there you define a _project_. If you separate your project definition into `./build.sbt` and your plugin definition into `project/plugins.sbt` you should be fine.